# jQuery Sort not descending

Tags: jquery, sorting

On click, I am trying to sort this class in the ascending order, then back to descending order. When I click It, the Sort works fine in the Ascending order, but does not work for descending. Please help me make this work. I think it has something to do with my else statement because the if statement works just fine. :)

```
$(".id").click(function(){
  var mylist = $('.sort');
  var listitems = mylist.children('tr').get();
  listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    if ((compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0){
      return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
      return (compB < compA)  ? 1:(compB > compB)? 1 : 0;
    }
  });
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
});
```

Comment: You're comparing `compB` to itself in the second return statement

Comment: Your `if condition` makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to toggle information about sort direction on the clicked button or link,
**Eg.** Store the sort direction within a data attribute like `data-sort-direction` which takes the values `asc` and `desc` or `0` for the *ascending* sort and `1` for the *descending* sort type.

So, on click you retrieve this attribute value and you sort your items according to its current value `asc` or `desc`, `0` or `1`, then use it  in the **.sort()** method to decide whether you have to return `1`, `-1` or `0`

```
if (an > bn) {
    return sortDirection === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
}
if (an < bn) {
    return sortDirection ==="asc" ? -1 : 1;
}
return 0;
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="id" data-sort-direction="asc">Sort</button>
<table id="sort" class="table">
    <tr data-name="John Doe">
        <td>Mr. John Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-name="Trent Richardson">
        <td>Mr. Trent Richardson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-name="Cindy Smith">
        <td>Ms. Cindy Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-name="Bill Williams">
        <td>Mr. Bill Williams</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-name="Jane Doe">
        <td>Mrs. Jane Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var mylist = $('#sort'),
    listitems = mylist.children('tbody').children('tr');
$('.id').on('click', function (e) {
    var button = $(this),sortDirection = button.data('sort-direction');
    // update data attribute for the next click
    sortDirection === "asc"?button.data('sort-direction', "desc"):button.data('sort-direction', "asc");
    listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
        var an = a.getAttribute('data-name'),
            bn = b.getAttribute('data-name');
        if (an > bn) {
            return sortDirection === "asc"?1:-1;
        }
        if (an < bn) {
            return sortDirection ==="asc"?-1:1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    listitems.detach().appendTo(mylist);
});
```

Be carefull when you retrieve `<tr>` items from `<table>` tag, there's an implicit `<tbody>` even if you omitted it in your html, so you have to get the `<tr>` items this way:

```
listitems = mylist.children('tbody').children('tr');
```

[Fiddle with `<tr>`](http://jsfiddle.net/q6op8tun/)

[Fiddle with `<div>`](http://jsfiddle.net/a4bqbm90/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your sort function to this:

```
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    if(compA < compB) {
        return -1;
    } else if(compA > compB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

You could also use the built in `Array` method to sort your array:

```
var sortedArr = Array.prototype.sort(listitems);
```

Comment: This looks cleaner, but when i click, it ascending, and still does not descend on the next click. I get the same result.

Comment: @DariusCastillo Sounds like it could be a problem outside of the algorithm. We would need sample HTML and array data.